# Progress bar not changing value when timer1_tick is invoked

Tags: c#, timer, progress-bar

```
int millisecondi = 0;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    player.Top = screen.Height - player.Height;
    player.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.stand;
    if (mario)
    {
        label1.Text = "Mario";
    }
    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
    progressBar1.Value = 100;
}


private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    index++;
    //replay gif 
    millisecondi++;
    if (millisecondi == 1000)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value - 1;
        if (progressBar1.Value <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sei Morto");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in the timer1_Tick.
It is enabled automatically and its interval is 1 millisecond.

Every second I want the progress bar to be "Progressbar value - 1" for example.
When it reaches 0 I want it to say "You died".

It enters in this cycle after 1 second, but it just doesn't work:

```
 if (millisecondi == 1000)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value - 1;

        if (progressBar1.Value <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sei Morto");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean!!! ProgressBar Update fails!!!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timer ticks once and then it stops: To make it tick constantly, change the `Tick` event to:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    index++;
    millisecondi++;
    timer1.Stop();
    if (millisecondi == 1000)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value - 1;

        if (progressBar1.Value <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sei Morto");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        timer1.Start(); // will 'retick' if millisecondi != 1000
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that code execution reaches to `if (millisecondi == 1000)` then there wouldn't be any problem with execution scenario so you should take care of other things like following:

Timer NameSpace : Make sure that your timer namespace is **System.Windows.Forms.Timer**

if It's ok that would work anyway your code looks correct to me, but if you still encounter this problem again try this code :

```
 index++;
        //replay gif 
        millisecondi++;

        if (millisecondi == 1000)
        {
            if (progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                progressBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)
                    delegate
                    {
                        progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value - 1;
                    }
                    );
            }
            else
            {
                progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value - 1;
            }
            if (progressBar1.Value <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sei Morto");
            }
        }
```